# create foreign key in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

is there anyone who can help me to create a foreign key for my Status table. I need to PLACE a foreign key constraint on the **code** in the status table, referring to the **id** in the Building table.

```
TABLE building
(
  build_name           VARCHAR2(50,0) NOT NULL,
  id            NUMBER (38,0) NOT NULL,
  mapid                NUMBER (10,0) NOT NULL
);

TABLE STATUS
(
  code         VARCHAR(2 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  status_name  VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT NULL,
);
```

Bulding table has constraint `building_gmidx` with `id` as primary key.

Comment: The tutorial is a good place to start: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10766/tdddg_objects.htm#TDDDG196

Comment: STATUS.CODE has a very different data type (`VARCHAR2(2 BYTE)`) than BUILDING.ID (`NUMBER(38,0)`); thus, it doesn't seem to that they contain the same values. Should there perhaps be a STATUS_CODE column on the BUILDING table?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick syntax for your current requirement, however I recommend you to go through the oracle documentation for a proper understanding of what this means.

```
ALTER TABLE STATUS ADD (
CONSTRAINT status_fk_building FOREIGN KEY (code)
REFERENCES building (id)   
ENABLE VALIDATE);
```

Comment: Does not work. I get this error:SQL Error: ORA-02267: column type incompatible with referenced column type
02267. 00000 -  "column type incompatible with referenced column type"
*Cause:    The datatype of the referencing column is incompatible with the

Answer (score 0):

Did you leave out `CREATE TABLE *name*` to save time when writing the question?   The first thing I see is that your Foreign key has to have the same data type and size as your Primary key.  If the Tables already exist the code would be:

```
ALTER TABLE status MODIFY (code NUMBER(38));
```

From there you would need to

```
ALTER TABLE status ADD FOREIGN KEY (code) REFERENCES (building_gmidx)
```

Why is the constraint for building Primary key named `building_gmidx` and the column plain id??  All Normalized table attributes should be Unique.  Wouldn't it be better if you just named the column "id" `building_gmidx` instead. Just in case there are other types of id's added later you do not have to think about which table "id" pertains to. Let me know if this works.